# FluentValidation and custom message that tells the user which values are allowed/expected

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Consider the following validator, which works as expected:

```
public class NewOrderSingleValidator : AbstractValidator<NewOrderSingle>
{
    public NewOrderSingleValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.OrdType.getValue())
            .Must(p => p == OrdType.LIMIT || p == OrdType.MARKET)
            .WithMessage("Provided OrdType is not allowed, the value was: {PropertyValue}")
            .When(o => o.IsSetOrdType());
    }
}
```

Whenever the validation fails the validation results contains the error `Provided OrdType is not allowed, the value was: FOO`. Okay great!

But now I am wondering how I would be able to tell the user which values are allowed, without repeating my rules in the message.

I don't really understand what the [documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/configuring.html) means by:

> ‘{PropertyValue}’ - The value of the property being validated These include the predicate validator (‘Must’ validator), the email and the regex validators.

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
public class NewOrderSingleValidator : AbstractValidator<NewOrderSingle>
{
    public NewOrderSingleValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.OrdType.getValue())
            .Must(p => p == OrdType.LIMIT || p == OrdType.MARKET)
            .WithMessage("Error! Provided value: {PropertyValue}! Expected values: {Must}")
            .When(o => o.IsSetOrdType());
    }
}
```

That should generate the following message (or similar): `Error! Provided value: FOO! Expected LIMIT or MARKET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case you can try refactoring code to something like this:

```
var allowed = new [] {OrdType.LIMIT, OrdType.MARKET};
RuleFor(o => o.OrdType.getValue())
        .Must(p => allowed.Contains(p))
        .WithMessage($"Error! Provided value: {{PropertyValue}}! Expected values: {string.Join(", ", allowed)}")
        .When(o => o.IsSetOrdType());
```

> I don't really understand what the documentation means by:

It means that `PropertyValue` placeholder will be substituted by value provided to corresponding [validator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html). Some of the build in ones have more placeholders than just `PropertyValue` and `PropertyName`.